# Project Server 2013 Overriden SharePoint 2013 License

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

**Background:** I have a farm with 2WFE,2App and 1 DB server. I installed SharePoint 2013 Trail version on machines and then installed Project Server 2013 on top of it. I have installed SP1 and December 2015 CU of both SharePoint and Project servers on all machines respectively. Everything is working fine.

**Problem:** I purchased both SharePoint and Project Server License keys from Microsoft and when I tried to put the SharePoint Server 2013 key in *Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Convert License* Type it shows **Project Server 2013** instead of **SharePoint Server 2013 Trail Version**. When i tried to provide SharePoint Server 2013 Key, it refused to accept. I put Project Server 2013 key, it accepted but now showing nothing against *Current License*. The *Enter The Product Key* box is also disabled.

Any idea to convert SharePoint License? I am afraid it will expire after the trail period as it never accepted the SharePoint license key i provided.

Answer (score 1):

Project Server is a superset license of SharePoint Server. You don't need to do anything except input the Project Server license key.

Comment: Thank you Trevor. Can you please share a Microsoft reference on this?